# WIFI not connecting after suspend, WIFI driver missing after reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, suspend

A few weeks ago I got an old laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it. When I suspend the machine and wake it back up, the WIFI won't connect (looks like it tries to connect to a SSID but can't).

When I cut the power by shutting down and powering back up, everything is back to normal.
When I reboot the machine instead, it boots and says it doesn't have any WIFI drivers enabled.

All relevant power saving settings in BIOS are deactivated.

Here is the lshw -C network output for

when it all works:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 0c
   serial: a0:1d:48:a8:2b:df
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0600000-d0600fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff


*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: fc:4d:d4:56:2c:ac
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x0e driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=1.0.07-b370 ip=192.168.43.226 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0500000-d05fffff
```

After suspension (WIFI coming up but not able to connect):

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: a0:1d:48:a8:2b:df
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0600000-d0600fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: fc:4d:d4:56:2c:ac
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x0e driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=1.0.07-b370 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0500000-d05fffff
```

After reboot after suspension (driver missing):

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 0c
   serial: a0:1d:48:a8:2b:df
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0600000-d0600fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0500000-d05fffff
```

Additional information:
I have tried going back to 20.04 and even briefly tried Linux Mint, the issue is the same on all Linux distributions, it is not an issue when I boot into windows.

Comment: Windows, you say? Please check here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 The issue is not tied to dual-boot. I have tried it just now on a clear install, still can replicate all the errors reliably. Could any additional output help?

Comment: When it is not working: `sudo dmesg | grep -i mt76`